# Ruby rails - list active sessions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any way to get the list of all active sessions in rails? I have memory cached session list, and I want to view the user ids, source ip, time stamp, duration etc. for basic administration purposes.

Comment: Just a heads-up, using the memory session store is not recommended in production, as it won't be shared across processes. Also, unless you're using the database store, doing this is probably going to be rather complicated and hacky.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall. thanks, that is a good thing to know.

Comment: What are you using for authentication? Some of the different options out there have built in ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment, I am doing something similar to what you want to do. I am using authlogic but I imagine that you can do something equivalent with other authentication packages.

I am using authlogic's auto logout capabilities and have it set to log people out after 120 minutes. Knowing that, generating a list is simple. I just do the following:

```
<% User.find(:all, :conditions => ["last_request_at > ?", 120.minutes.ago]).each do |user| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to user.name, admin_person_path(user.bio) %>
    (<%= mail_to user.email %>) <%= time_ago_in_words(user.last_request_at) %> ago
  </li>
<% end %>
```

You can see that I just list their names, e-mails, and when they last made a request. It would be trivial to add last_login_ip, current_login_at, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sean. That code looks good. I am using OmniAuth, let me see what options I have there.